# Friends can't see my tagged "Photos of You," only my boyfriend and sister can

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I noticed that when I "view as" and type in a friend's name, they can't see the photos that I am tagged in. the "photos of you" is blank. I thought it was because it is the setting of the person who tagged me in and but even when I go to "view as" and type in the name of the person who tagged me and then I go to "photos of you", it is still blank.

I changed all my privacy settings to "friends" and all tagged photos are allowed on timeline but even when I go to my tagged photo album, I can only see some of it but if I go to my timeline, the photos are there.

Then when I "view as" and type in my sister's name or boyfriend's name, they can see all the photos that I am tagged in. no one has been added to a list or is restricted, and I have not set any settings for only my bf and sister. I even got a new friend to add me thinking that there is an unknown setting to all my friends except my sister and bf but even that new person can't view my tagged photos.

Comment: Just ask to any of your friends(except boyfriend and sister) if they are able to see photos of your from their timeline or not.

Answer (score 2):

Under **Settings** → **Timeline and Tagging**, I would look at these two items:

- Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?
- When you’re tagged in a post, who do you want to add to the audience if they aren’t already in it?

Make sure they are both set to *Friends* (particularly that first one).

[image: Timeline and Tagging]